# Cannot open include file: "ui_window.h" - Visual 2012 + Qt add-in

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012

I created my program in QtCreator, but now I have to move it to VS2012 (with Qt add-in 5.2.1). But visual doesn't find the ui files. I get:

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file "ui_window.h": No such file or directory"
```

1. Yes, I write #include "ui_window.h"
2. I tried two ways to do that:

   - creating new project and adding existing files
   - creating new project and creating new classes, and then copy code from old files to new files (named the same)

If anyone knows where the problem is?

Comment: Where does the "ui_window.h" file exist? It should be in the same directory as the file that contains `#include "ui_window.h"`.

Comment: Yes, it is in the same directory

Comment: Have you tried adding the current working directory to the include path explicitly?

Comment: Ok, it started to working when I move #include "ui_window.h" to .h file, because visual had created it in .cpp file. I don't know why, but it depends on it.

Answer (score 4):

I have had the same issue.

Does it create a header file "ui_window.h" from a file "window.ui" and put it to a directory $(ProjectDir)\GeneratedFiles?

Also you could try to compile "*.ui" file by right mouse click/compile or Ctrl+F7

If Visual Studio doesn't compile the file then check properties of the "*.ui" file:

1) check "Configuration properties/General/Item type: Custom Build
   Tool"
 2) check "Custom Build Tool/general/Commad Line, Description and
   other arguments".

If it's empty or not set than try to reinstall "Qt Visual Studio Add-in".

Answer (score 2):

Hm, I had the same problem, In my case i fixed it by first clicking on the .ui form file in visual studio, creating some qui in qtDesigner, then I commented out the include causing the problem, built the solution using release mode, got errors, re enableled the include file, and Voila it works perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem just like this in Visual Studio with the Qt Addon and I managed to fix it by specifying the location of the generated ui_.h file. Right-click `solution > Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Additional Include Directories` and add the location of the ui_.h `$(IntDir)uic\`. In my case I ran into this problem when trying to compile the tests for my Qt Project using the GoogleTest that were in a separate solution so I had to specify that specific solution as a prefix `$(SolutionDir)SolutionName\$(IntDir)uic\`.